# Memory layout exercise C++

Tags: c++, memory-layout

I'm reading B.Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" and I'm trying to do most of the exercises. This one is very interesting and I have no idea where to start.

The exercise is :

> Consider the layout in 17.4. Write a program that tells the order in which static storage, the stack, and the free store are laid out in memory. In which direction does the stack grow : upward toward higher addresses or downward toward lower addresses?

Layout in 17.4 :

> Code - memory for code
>
> Static data - space for global variables
>
> Free store - available memory
>
> Stack - memory for calling functions and space for their arguments and local variables

How can i actually know in what order this all is happening? Better yet how could I actually output the order in what this is happening at the time it happens?

Isn't it supposed to be handled by compiler or maybe i just misunderstood the exercise? Few tips would be really cool!

Thanks

Comment: Print out pointers to things that exist in each of those segments. Although this presumes that the pointer values actually correspond to physical memory locations...

Comment: Please be a bit more specific in your question.  If you can narrow you question down to _one_ question that would be great.  For example, what is "it" in "Isn't it supposed to be handled by compiler"?

Comment: Yes, by it i mean all of this memory giving to different parts of the program ( global variables, stack, free store). All i know is that compiler is doing this stuff for us but as i understand i have to somehow make the program that shows in what order compiler is doing what he's doing

Comment: I would know how to print a pointer to global variable but how about 'Stack'?  - memory that's allocated for functions and its arguments? Should i create pointer that's pointing to one of function arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't it supposed to be handled by compiler

The *linker*, more specifically.

Here's a starting point, doing exactly what Joseph Mansfield suggests.

```
#include <iostream>

int static_data;

int main()
{
    int stack_data;

    if ( &static_data < &stack_data )
    {
        std::cout << "Static data is in lower memory than the stack.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool now i got it :) Thanks to everyone guys :)

Comment: It'd be interesting to test if your compiler puts `int mutable_global` in a different location than `const int const_global`, and also `static int static_mutable_global` and `static const int static_const_global`.  You'd have to "interleave" them and see which ones become "un-interleaved".

Comment: This was my 1st question in this forum and I'm amazed how fast things are getting answered here. So cool!